# Set Excel label forecolor using theme color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set the color of a label using one of the theme colors. For example, I want to set

```
lblExample.forecolor = xlThemeColorAccent2
```

That doesn't work and I can't find a work around

Answer (score 2):

`xlThemeColorAccent2` is only an index, so you need to find the list of values where the index can be used to get the full color value - and that's here:

```
Label1.ForeColor = ThisWorkbook.Colors(xlThemeColorAccent2)
```